# I want a way to render components in a page only when its scrolled to its position in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was working with a site the other day, I needed it to look fancy and wanted the components inside it to render only when the page's scrolled to a particular point. I found a glitchy way to do it like this, and it seldom works:

```
const placeComponent = () => {if(window.scrollY === 668){return(some jsx)} else return null}
```

And then in the main component, I would do like this

```
const App = () => {return(<>{placeComponent()}</>)}
```

It works sometimes cause I need to be very specific about the page's scroll position. **Please suggest something robust. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

```
var bottom =
 $(window).height() - $(`#element`).offset().top - $(`#element`).height();
        
        
const placeComponent = () => 
{if(window.scrollY === bottom){return(some jsx)} else return null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [react-intersection-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer). It's

> React implementation of the Intersection Observer API to tell you when
> an element enters or leaves the viewport

See the [demo](https://react-intersection-observer.now.sh/).

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but I didnot want to use a separate dependency here. Thanks anyways